# how to download a .csv file from a web to computer using python

Tags: python, web, download

I'm a stock market trader and at the end of every trading session I have some files to download from stock exchange website, how can I write a code in python or in any other language to download a file and perhaps schedule it for downloading..?

Comment: What environment are you working in?  Windows, Mac, Linux?

Comment: I'm working on windows 10

Comment: If it's just a dumb file download (i.e. the remote filename is always the same, the file doesn't need any post-download processing, etc.), then [wget](https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/) might be the best solution.  You can schedule it to run every day with the [SCHTASKS](https://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html) command.